# Sending nil to CGPoint type parameter

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have this method:

```
- (void)placeView:(UIView*)theView withCenterIn:(CGPoint)centerPoint;
```

So I pass the view and a point to te the view's center.

But it happens that I do not need to specify the center, just the view.

Passing "nil" leads to error.

Please, suggest how to skip passing the center point.

Keep in mind that I need to use that method like this:

```
- (void)placeView:(UIView*)theView withCenterIn:(CGPoint)centerPoint{
    if(centerPoint == nil){//and I understand that it's a wrong comparison, as I cannot pass "nil" to CGPoint
        //set a random center point
    }
    else{
        //set that view to the specified point
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CGPoint` is a C `struct`, you cannot pass `nil` for it. You can create a  separate method that does not take the unnecessary `CGPoint`, and get rid of your `if` statement, like this:

```
- (void)placeView:(UIView*)theView withCenterIn:(CGPoint)centerPoint{
    //set that view to the specified point
}

- (void)placeView:(UIView*)theView {
    //set a random center point
}
```

If you insist on keeping one method, you could designate one point as "special" (say, `CGMakePoint(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)`), wrap it in a `#define`, and use instead of `nil`.

Yet another solution would be to wrap your `CGPoint` in `NSValue`:

```
NSValue *v = [NSValue withPoint:CGMakePoint(12, 34)];
CGPoint p = [v pointValue];
```

Comment: @SavaMazăre Right, this approach is cleaner both on your implementation (no unnecessary `if`) and on your callers (no unnecessary `withCenterIn:nil`).

Comment: I understand, that makes sense. But what if I need to specify 2 different points, example: placeView:witCenterIn:orOriginAt: and I am checking if I have got the center, I work with the center, else I work with origin. I was thinking of passing an array of CGPoints, and checking if object at index:0 is nil, so I didnt get the center -- > I will use the origin (assuming actually an array with 2 objects, one of them to be nil).

Comment: @SavaMazăre You can provide a separate method `placeView:withOriginIn:`, or you could use the "special" point. There's also an `NSValue` route that lets you pass `nil` values, but it is not as type-safe.

Comment: Aha, and NSValue IS an object, and IS able to be nil, and IS able to be checked is it nil or not, right? So instead, I can work with NSValue, passing it to my method?

Comment: @SavaMazăre Correct - it is an object, so it allows sending `nil`s.

Answer (score 13):

You can't use `nil` as a "no point" indicator, because it is only for objects, and `CGPoint` is a `struct`. (As dasblinkenlight has already said.)

In my geometry library, I've defined a "null" `CGPoint` to use as a "no point" placeholder, and a function to test for it. Since the components of a `CGPoint` are `CGFloat`s, and `float`s have a "invalid value" representation already -- `NAN`, defined in math.h -- I think that's the best thing to use:

```
// Get NAN definition
#include <math.h>

const CGPoint WSSCGPointNull = {(CGFloat)NAN, (CGFloat)NAN};

BOOL WSSCGPointIsNull( CGPoint point ){
    return isnan(point.x) && isnan(point.y);
}
```