# How to check if a CGSize is initialized (or if its value is different from "nil")

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I have a CGSize property in a class and I need to check if it has been initialized. I know that a CGSize isn't a object, but generally speaking, is the same idea of checking if an object is different from nil. How to do that?

Comment: Related: [Sending nil to CGPoint type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987142/sending-nil-to-cgpoint-type-parameter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "in a class". If this is an instance variable, your problems are over, because you are guaranteed that an instance variable will be auto initialized to some form of zero (i.e. `CGSizeZero`). But if you just mean "in my code somewhere", e.g. an automatic variable, then there is no such test; it is entirely up to you to initialize before use, and until you do, the value could be anything at all (sorry, but that's how C works).

On the whole, your question is itself a "bad smell". If it matters to you at some point in your code whether this value has been initialized, then you are doing it wrong. It's your value; it was up to you to initialize it (e.g. when your overall object was initialized). Or, if for some reason you need to know whether your setter has ever been called, then you need to add a boolean to your setter that *tells* whether it has ever been called.

Comment: You are right. I'm going with the first approach. In my case, I can initialize with a default value. Please, could you add the function CGSizeEqualToSize to your answer? Just for reference. Thanks.

Comment: The "reference" is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 19):

You can compare it to CGSizeZero or an arbitrary size that you consider invalid.

```
if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(CGSizeZero, mySize)) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: You are right. My question was horrible. Although this isn't the correct answer, it helped me. My real question should be "How to compare two CGSize values" (that, by the way, already exists). Thanks for pointing that anyway.

Comment: code works like a charm. just a syntax mistake, a ")" is missing, if(!CGSizeEqualToSize(CGSizeZero, mySize)) {
       // do something
    }

Answer (score 3):

`CGSize` is a C struct.  With few exceptions (when used as an iVar), there is no guarantee for its initialized value.  It could be anything, especially when created on the stack.

Thus, you are responsible for initializing it properly, and since "zeros" are valid values, there is no guaranteed way to tell if it was set to "zero" on purpose, or it has been uninitialized.

Comment: This answer is correct.